# Problema de PHP en MAC

Tags: php, xampp, macos, crud

tengo un problema bastante raro en mi proyecto, por si alguien amablemente me puede ayudar, lo qué pasa es que antiguamente estaba utilizando un computador con Windows y actualmente me cambie al sistema MacOS. En mi sistema Windows utilizaba el servidor local de Xampp y ahora en mi sistema MacOS igual estoy utilizando Xampp. Lo que pasa es que cree un formulario de servicio tecnico para usuarios dentro del sistema, en el cual toma algunos datos de los Input y los guardada en la base de datos, aqui todo bien, el tema es que en mi sistema MacOs no guarda los datos pero en mi computador con Windows si. Lo mas raro es que en mi sistema MacOs queda en blanco solo muestra la URL y no arroja error en console. Cual podría ser la solución? De antemano gracias[image: Al momento que envió el formulario me aparece lo de la imagen 2]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][![No me carga y se queda en blanco][2][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utA2Y.jpg)
[image: codigo fuente]

Comment: Escribe esto en la terminal: `php -v` y dinos qué versión de PHP se muestra.

Comment: Primero revisa si son la misma versión como dice el comentario anterior e indicanoslo, en segunda instancia revisa el archivo php.ini de ambos equipos en la sección Dynamic Extensions, puede que sea una extensión que no esta habilitada en Mac. ¿El proyecto esta hecho en algún Framework? Y si es así ¿En cual?

Comment: Hola Victor ¿Y tienes acceso al Xampp en windows? Por lo que comentas pareciera ser un problema de las librerías de PHP instaladas en cada ambiente. También puedes entrar al archivo php.ini que se encuentra en la instalación de Xampp (Normalmente está en /Applications/XAMPP/etc/php. ini o en /opt/lampp/etc/php según la versión) y cambiar la siguientes líneas : > display_errors -> si está en Off, colocarlo en On <br />
> error_reporting -> colocarlo como E_ALL si tiene algún texto distinto y de ahi reiniciar Xampp o el servidor Apache, para que te empiece a mostrar errores. Puedes colocar el me

Comment: Cuando salga la pantalla en blanco, por favor ve al xampp y revisa los logs de PHP. Traes eso y el código de las consultas que dices que se hacen y **los pones en la pregunta**, yendo a [edit] y poniendo todo eso **como texto**

Comment: Algo importante a revisar son los archivos requeridos (`require`, `include`). Como windows es insensible a mayúsculas, las rutas de los archivos también lo son, cosa que cambia al portar a otra plataforma, revisa que las importaciones sean exactamente como se llaman los archivos. Por otro lado, es usual que la base de datos MySQL tenga el mismo comportamiento, insensible en Windows, pero estricto en MacOS/Linux; revisa que los nombres de tablas y columnas sean exactos en el código.